# Entries in the web config are constantly added

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, web-config, safe-controls

I have an issues with the web config entries for safe controls, for some controls i have added a safe control to the file. I've done this in visual studio 'Safe control entries'. But any time i deploy the solution the entry is added EVEN if the entry is already in there, so after 10 deployments i have like 10 exactly the same entries.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the SafeControl entries as mentioned in below image. Maybe that help you.
[image]

Comment: Yes that is what i do, but everytime I do a VS deploy, it adds entries to the web config